# What are the differences between the @Input and @HostBinding decorators in Angular?

Tags: angular

These decorators looks like they are doing the same thing.

If I create a Directive, the Input and HostBinding decorators are receiving a value of a specific attribute from the template.

What are exatly the differencies between these decorators in Angular ?

Thanks guys.

EDIT:

@Segev gives an incorrect answer. According to Angular official documentation :

Input - Decorator that marks a class field as an input property and supplies configuration metadata. The input property is bound to a DOM property in the template. During change detection, Angular automatically updates the data property with the DOM property's value.

HostBinding - Decorator that marks a DOM property as a host-binding property and supplies configuration metadata. Angular automatically checks host property bindings during change detection, and if a binding changes it updates the host element of the directive.

As i can read in the Angular official documentation these decorators are similar and I don't understand the Segev answer....

Answer (score 1):

Two completely different things

`@Input()` - allows you to "inject" context into a component

`@HostBinding()` - let you access the element encapsulating (or "hosting") your component

Comment: Input - Decorator that marks a class field as an input property and supplies configuration metadata. The input property is bound to a DOM property in the template. During change detection, Angular automatically updates the data property with the DOM property's value.

HostBinding - Decorator that marks a DOM property as a host-binding property and supplies configuration metadata. Angular automatically checks host property bindings during change detection, and if a binding changes it updates the host element of the directive.

Comment: As i can read in the Angular official documentation these decorators are similar and I don't understand your answer....

Comment: Let's look at a use case :

You will use @Input() to communicate data into your component, here's an example : 
`
<my-component [myInput]="'context'">
`

Why you will use @HostBinding() when you want to access properties of a host component. Let's say you have a directive [mydirective] that you used to decorate a `<div>` tag - @HostBinding will allow you to access that `div` tag : 
`
<div myDirective></div>
`